# Google Places JS API, Street names in specific City

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I am busy making a website and i want to use the Javascript version of Google Places API, but i want it to only show street names in a specific city or in several specific city's.

Could someone please explain me how?

I already have it loaded but shows every possible output.

I used the following:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50">
```

Thanks already!

Comment: i think it's not possible to get address of specific city.

Answer (score 0):

Google maps does not provide the list of street names for a particular city. You can get the street names with the help of Google Places Autocomplete feature.

Take a look at the below link:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

Hope it helps. You can start type in any street or city ie. any place and u will get a list of places as autocomplete below.

Comment: And do you know how this can be done? I would really appreciatie your help